# Download VC++ 2008 Merge Modules without installing VS2008?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, deployment, dll, msvcrt

Is it possible to download the merge modules for VC++ 2008 (CRT) without having Visual Studio?

I have an old Visual Studio 6 project and an old Install Shield Installer. I am using some third-party dlls that are dependent on MSVCR90.DLL among others (installing the dll in my program folder doesn't work though maybe I am missing some others.)

What does make it work is manually installing the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable SP1 (vcredist_x86.exe) on the client machine.

I read [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2007/10/12/how-to-redistribute-the-visual-c-libraries-with-your-application.aspx) that the preferred way to distribute these pieces is through the associated merge modules.  But I can't find a way to get the merge modules if I don't already have VS 2008 installed!

By the way, the third-party dlls do come with their own OEM installer but it is 80 MB and I'm hoping to avoid having to distribute that as well.  The vcredist_x86.exe is only 4 MB.

Comment: You get the merge modules when you get a license for VS2008.  If you don't have the license then you need to ask somebody else to provide them to you, it is actually permitted by the license agreement.  But with the stipulation that whomever gives them to you has agree to that license first.  This is just the normal way that a company tries to make the life of paying customers simple.  With no obligation to non-paying customers.  This is the way the world works, it should be obvious.  If it is not then Linux is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for educating me Hans. I did buy VS2010 but see only the 2010 MSM files.  Do you think the installer includes the 2008 MSM modules as well?  I will ask my dll provider if they could give me the merge modules for their dll.

Comment: Asking your DLL provider for the files you need to properly deploy it is entirely reasonable.  No reason for him to not just give them to you.  Also ask for a 2010 build.